# conjure up error while installation cannot retrieve charm

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, canonical, conjure-up

I am deploying ubuntu openstack.
in conjure-up after initialization and deployment of nodes Os, conjure up crashes with this error:

```
cannot retrieve charm "cs:openstack-dashboard-252": cannot get archive: Get
https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v5/openstack-dashboard-252/archive: 
dial tcp: lookup api.jujucharms.com on 8.8.8.8:53: read udp
192.168.1.209:40701->8.8.8.8:53: i/o timeout
```

in both maas server and client node dns of **api.jujucharms.com** can resolves and I can `curl` that url.

screenshot attached for full details.
[image]

thank you in advance.

Comment: @battlemidget , do you see this question?
can you help me?

Comment: If no one know anything about this error and any solutions I will submit it as a bug in 8 hours!

Comment: also asked here https://github.com/conjure-up/conjure-up/issues/1542